# Pareto Random Variable-Conditional Expectation Logic

Tags: probability, poisson-distribution

Question:

$$\text {Let X be a Pareto random variable with } \lambda  = 3. $$

$$ Find: E[X | X > 0] $$

The solution given skips some steps which makes it a bit unclear to me. It makes sense logically but I want to derive the solution using symbols.

I tried doing this:

$$ \sum_{x=0}^\infty x * \frac{Pr[X > 0, X=x]} {Pr [X>0]} $$

The solution is just this:

$$ E[X | X > 0] = \frac{E[X]}{Pr[X>0]} $$

which leads me to believe that my expression simplifies to this:

$$ \frac{1}{Pr[X>0]}\sum_{x=0}^\infty x * Pr[X=x] = \frac{E[X]}{Pr[X>0]} $$

What is the logic that makes $$ Pr[X>0, X = x] = Pr[X=x]? $$

I tried doing this also using the Bayes rule as well, like this:

$$ \sum_{x=0}^\infty x * \frac{Pr[X>0 | X = x] * Pr[X = x]}{Pr[X>0]} $$

which would imply that $$ Pr[X>0 | X = x] = 1 $$ to give us the same answer as above.

Can somebody explain this logic to me? For some reason this escapes me and losing sleep over this sucks. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X|X>0]Pr(X>0)+\mathbb{E}[X|X=0]Pr(X=0)$$

Hence

$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X|X>0]Pr(X>0)+0$$

That is 
$$\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{E}[X|X>0]Pr(X>0)$$

Final conclusion:

$$\mathbb{E}[X|X>0]=\frac{\mathbb{E}[X]}{Pr(X>0)}$$

Remark:

$$Pr(X>0, X=x)=Pr(X=x)$$ is not true when $x=0$.

Comment: Oh man....how blatantly obvious. That's why my logic was confusing me with the remark, because of the case where x=0, and so I was quite lost.

So a simple condition on X >0 and X = 0 solves this. Thanks! And of course, E[X | X = 0] is 0 since this is just equal to E[0] = 0...makes complete sense. Thank you.